# How to do join one hive table with another remote hive table

Tags: hive, hbase

We have a computing scenario that is we need to do join operation for 2 tables in Hive.

For example, in clusterA we create a table A in Hive and in clusterB, we created a table B in Hive which is mapping to a Hbase table in clusterB. Then we want to write below SQL statement in Hive in clusterA like this :

```
select a.col1, b.col2 from ta inner join tb@remote_hive on ta.col3 = tb.col3
```

Just like the conception database link in Oracle.
Is there a way allow us to do it like this? if yes, can you give us an example.

Comment: Every Hive query is translated to a sequence of Hadoop jobs and those jobs are submitted to Hadoop job tracker. For a Hadoop job (mappers and reducers) any Hive table is merely a collection of HDFS files located under the same folder (or partition within that folder). The problem is that HDFS files on cluster B are probably invisible on cluster A. If so, the Hadoop jobs associated with the relevant Hive query and launched on cluster A, won't be able to read HDFS files from cluster B.

Answer (score 2):

It's not (directly) possible. There are at least 2 ways around it though:

- tools like [Waggle Dance](https://github.com/HotelsDotCom/waggle-dance), a Hive federation service.
- since hive 2.3.0, Hive has a [jdbc storage handler](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/StorageHandlers), letting you query remote tables via jdbc.